# Proving that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let $A$ be the set of all statement forms in three variables $p$, $q$, and $r$.  Let $R$ be the relation defined on $A$ as follows: For all $P$ and $Q$ in $A$, 
$$P\; R\; Q \longleftrightarrow P\; \mbox{and}\; Q\; \mbox{have the same truth table.}$$
Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: ive been looking at it for a couple hours and i dont even know where to begin

Comment: @JohnMaddux we don't edit out the details of the question once it has been answered. On the other hand, I'm not sure how to do the Rollback thing, so I'll just edit the question back in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

equivalence relations have three properties, check them one by one for your 'same truth table' relation

Comment: yes, reflexive, symmetric, transitive. how would i find these properties from a truth table?

Comment: you don't even need to know what a truth table is. you need to check (1) '$P$ has the same truth table as $P$', (2) 'if $P$ has the same truth table as $Q$ then $Q$ has the same truth table as $P$' and (3) 'if $P$ has the same truth table as $Q$ and $Q$ has the same truth table as $S$ then $p$ has the same truth table as $S$'

Comment: maybe i misread the question. my understanding was that pRq <--> p has the same truth table as q.  does this mean that pRq has the same truth table as p?

Comment: no, $R$ is shorthand for 'has the same truth table as'

Comment: i did not know that! thanks! this makes the problem very simple!